# Decrypt a pdf file using bouncy castle using 3des algorithm

Tags: c#, encryption

i need to decrypt a pdf file using bouncy castle libreries.
I use c#.

I can encrypt a pdf file using the following code:

```
 public static byte[] CmsEncrypt3DES(string InFilePath, string CertFilePath)
    {
        byte[] encoded;
        try
        {
            byte[] numArray = File.ReadAllBytes(InFilePath);
            X509Certificate x509Certificate =ESCmsEncrypt.LoadCertificate(CertFilePath);
            CmsEnvelopedDataGenerator cmsEnvelopedDataGenerator = new CmsEnvelopedDataGenerator();
            CmsProcessableByteArray cmsProcessableByteArray = new CmsProcessableByteArray(numArray);
            cmsEnvelopedDataGenerator.AddKeyTransRecipient(x509Certificate);
            encoded = cmsEnvelopedDataGenerator.Generate(cmsProcessableByteArray, PkcsObjectIdentifiers.DesEde3Cbc.Id).GetEncoded();
        }
        catch (Exception exception1)
        {
            Exception exception = exception1;
            throw exception;
        }
        return encoded;
    }
```

I import the certificate using this method:

```
         public static X509Certificate LoadCertificate(string filename)
    {
        X509Certificate x509Certificate;
        try
        {
            X509CertificateParser x509CertificateParser = new X509CertificateParser();
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
            X509Certificate x509Certificate1 = x509CertificateParser.ReadCertificate(fileStream);
            fileStream.Close();
            x509Certificate = x509Certificate1;
        }
        catch (Exception exception1)
        {
            Exception exception = exception1;
            Log.LogError("ESCmsEncrypt.LoadCertificate", exception.Message, exception.ToString());
            throw exception;
        }
        return x509Certificate;
    }
```

This code work well but i' don't know how to decrypt this file using bouncy castle.
I've tried but without results.

Thanks

Valerio M.

***EDIT***

i've also used this code but it doesn't work:

```
 public static void  test()
    {
        X509Certificate2Collection scollection = new X509Certificate2Collection();

        // Output which certificate will be used
        Console.WriteLine("Using Certificate:");

        string path_certificato = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["certificate_file"].ToString();
        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2();
        X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(path_certificato));
       
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("1.\tFull DN: {0}", x509.Subject);
        Console.WriteLine("\tThumbprint: {0}", x509.Thumbprint);
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------");

        cert = x509;
        scollection.Add(cert);
        // Wait
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey(true);

        // Create data for encryption
        string message = "THIS IS OUR SECRET MESSAGE";
        byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

        // Encrypt
        Console.WriteLine("Encrypting message...");

        //ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(data); // will use default ContentInfo Oid, which is "DATA"
        // Explicitly use ContentInfo Oid 1.2.840.113549.1.7.1, "DATA", which is the default.
        ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(new System.Security.Cryptography.Oid("1.2.840.113549.1.7.1"), data);

        // If using OID 1.2.840.113549.3.7 (the default one used if empty constructor is used) or 1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.3.6  everything works
        // If using OID 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.42 (AES CBC) it breaks
        AlgorithmIdentifier encryptionAlgorithm = new AlgorithmIdentifier(new System.Security.Cryptography.Oid("1.2.840.113549.3.7"));
        EnvelopedCms envelopedCms = new EnvelopedCms(contentInfo); // this will use default encryption algorithm (3DES)
        //EnvelopedCms envelopedCms = new EnvelopedCms(contentInfo, encryptionAlgorithm);
        Console.WriteLine("Encyption Algorithm:" + envelopedCms.ContentEncryptionAlgorithm.Oid.FriendlyName);
        Console.WriteLine("Encyption Algorithm:" + envelopedCms.ContentEncryptionAlgorithm.Oid.Value);
        CmsRecipientCollection recipients = new CmsRecipientCollection(SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber, scollection);
        /*Console.WriteLine("Receipientinfo count: " + encryptionEnvelopedCms.RecipientInfos.Count.ToString());
        foreach (var i in encryptionEnvelopedCms.RecipientInfos)
        {
            Console.Write("RecipientInfo Encryption Oid: " + i.KeyEncryptionAlgorithm.Oid);
        }
        */
        envelopedCms.Encrypt(recipients);
        byte[] encryptedData = envelopedCms.Encode();
        Console.WriteLine("Message encrypted!");

        EnvelopedCms envelopedCms_new = new EnvelopedCms();
        envelopedCms_new.Decode(encryptedData);
        envelopedCms_new.Decrypt(scollection);
        byte[] decryptedData = envelopedCms_new.ContentInfo.Content;
    }
```

"envelopedCms_new.Decode(encryptedData);"this part doesn't work
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Impossibile trovare la proprietà o l'oggetto.

Comment: i need to complete the code i've posted adding a decrypt method. Using a certificate .cer i need to decrypt these pdf  using this non standard approach.In fact i can't open these "crypted" files using adobe!

Comment: I need a way to decriptare

Comment: I need a way to decrypt the file or rhe string i ve created using that method. I know how to do using a simple password as key, but i not able to use a certificate.